# React Native - navigation.navigate is not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am a newbie in react native, I am facing some worst kind of behavior of react native. For example, if I try to navigate the user with navigation.navigate, it does not work, but when I try to navigate with navigation.reset, then it navigates the user. Can someone please explain it? I saw some questions here similar to my question but the answers there did not satisfy me. Thanks for your time.

The navigation.navigate which did not work is

```
navigation.navigate('Home');
```

The reset function which worked is

```
navigation.reset({
  index: 0,
  routes: [{ name: 'Home' }],
});
```

Comment: can you share your navigation stack how you structured it? So it's easy to identify.

Comment: There is no any logic in my code for navigation. I am navigating with just a condition based on boolean value, either true or false. So if I try to navigate with navigation.navigate then it does not work, but when I use navigation.reset, then it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')`

And declare your home screen in App navigator or auth navigator